# Continuously write data from memory to response stream

Tags: java, servlets, response, pdfbox

So I'm using PDFBox to spit out an auto-generated PDF document based off an existing template. I used PDFMergerUtility to achieve somewhat of a solution:

```
PDFMergerUtility finalDoc = new PDFMergerUtility(); 
for (StudentEN student : students) {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("template.pdf");
    PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true);

    contentStream.beginText();
    // Draw stuff
    contentStream.endText();

    contentStream.close();

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(out);
    finalDoc.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
    document.close();
}

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
finalDoc.setDestinationStream(response.getOutputStream());
finalDoc.mergeDocuments();
```

The problem with this is the entire document (which can be very big) is served straight from memory, so depending on its size, an OutOfMemoryError is likely to occur. A solution I've come up with that works is keeping the file on disk, and appending to it for each loop, then streaming the resulting file using IOUtils, but I was wondering if there was some way I could just continuously write each document in the loop from memory to the response stream without having to write to disk. When I try writing to the response from within the loop, the client only receives the first document, and ignores all subsequent loops. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are doing is the right way to go about this. Merge the files first, then stream the merged file. I would go read the documentation to identify why you are only seeing one document.

Comment: The architecture of PDFBox generally does not support writing finalized parts of the PDF while still building the document. The only exception coming to my mind being the editing of an existing PDF and writing as an incremental update. In that case you can already send the former revision while still editing in memory.